# I get error message, VB.net trying to connect to Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g

I'd like to connect my vb.net (2013) to Oracle express 11g, but I get an error:

> A first chance exception of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

This is my code :

```
  Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client

    Sub ConectToOracle()

       Dim constring As String 

       constring = "Data Source=127.0.0.1:8080/XE;DBA PRIVILEGE=SYSDBA;User Id=MyName;Password=12345;" 

       Dim con As New OracleConnection(constring) 

       With con     
         Con.Open()
       End With

    End Sub
```

Then, I added `oracle.dataaccess` to my references, but nothing changes.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Your ip address is local, not going to get Oracle locally. Please check the connection string at ConnectionStrings.com

Comment: thank you for reply, i try all of connection string from connectionstring.com ,but there's not solve this problem.

Comment: If you update your post with the connection strings you tried, maybe someone can see the error. Not posting it will definitely not get you any help.